# How to edit pending commands during an interactive git rebase?

Tags: git, rebase

After editing some commits during a rebase I changed my mind about what I want to do to the following commits. How do I edit the remaining commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`git rebase --edit-todo`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase---edit-todo) command.

Description from [`git-rebase(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

> Edit the todo list during an interactive rebase.

And after the edit, continue the rebase using `git rebase --continue`.